# how to change site tag line for particular pages

Tags: navigation

I need to change my site tag line. Basically, this is school site we create for xyz higher sec school and ABC Nursery school; so I need to add both as a tag line in my site if I use xyz higher sec school I can't be able to use ABC NURSERY for those particular pages.

I need to change tagline for around only 6 pages; kindly suggest me for that.

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly it sounds like you will need to create a child theme, and instead of outputting the site tagline for certain pages, you'll need a conditional to output the other wording you want to appear there.

Comment: yes obviously correct

Comment: Welcome to [wordpress.se]. I hope you find the answer(s) you are looking for. Our site is different from most - if you have not done so yet, consider checking out the [tour](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tour) and [help center](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help) to find out how things work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your theme is using the WordPress site tagline, you should be able to filter it. `get_bloginfo( 'description' )` will call `get_option( 'blogdescription' );`, and we can filter the value of an option using the `option_{$option}` hook.

Let's suppose, for this code sample, that you want to change the tagline on 3 pages, with the titles **Kindergarten**, **Nursery School**, and **Babysitting**.

```
add_filter( 'option_blogdescription', 'wpse368031_change_tagline' );
function wpse368031_change_tagline( $tagline ) {
    $pages = array( 'Kindergarten', 'Nursery School', 'Babysitting' );
    if ( is_page( $pages ) ) {
        $tagline = 'ABC Nursery';
    }
    return $tagline;
}
```

Try adding this code to your active theme's `functions.php` file.

### Reference

- [`get_bloginfo( 'description' )`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_bloginfo/)
- [`option_{$option}` hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/option_option/)
- [`is_page()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page/)

Comment: its working fine thanks a lot @Pat J